# HTML, CSS auto scroll page to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have built a messenger application that runs on a webpage. As more input is entered (and the pages height increase)the text goes off the bottom of the screen and the user must scroll down. Is there a way to automatically have the page constantly scroll to the bottom to avoid this issue.The page also has a bootstrap header and foot which must remain in view at all times. Is this possible with css or how would I implement it?

```
body {
  padding: 5%;
  padding-top: 13%;
  background-image: url(/img/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;   
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with jQuery (or JavaScript for that matter).  But you can't do this in only CSS.

Here's your new code:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $("html, body").scrollTop($("body").height());
},10);
```

```js
//Stick to bottom code
setInterval(function () {
  $("html, body").scrollTop($("body").height());
},10);

//Expanding body width
//  - This isn't what you'd add to your code
setInterval(function () {
  $("<div>")
    .addClass("build")
    .appendTo("#container");
},500);
```

```css
div.build {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```